# Units in residue classes modulo prime ideal

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, primitive-roots

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ be its ring of integers with unit rank $\geq 1$. For a given prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, shall we say that the map $\mathcal{O}_K^\times \to (\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p})^\times$ is surjective, where $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ is the unit group.

Comment: Have you tried it with $K= \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I am taking number fields $K$ with unit rank at least one.

Comment: This is not always true, see e.g. Chen, Kitaoka, Yu - Distribution of units of real quadratic number fields - 2000.

Comment: You could also look at the fundamental units, $\epsilon_D$, of real quadratic fields and find one with a prime $p\ge 5$ such that $p| \mathrm{Norm}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})/\mathbb{Q}}(\epsilon_D-1) $.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141886/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually, I am looking for only one prime ideal so that the canonical map from the units is surjective.

Comment: Are you saying that when $\mathcal O_K^\times$ is infinite (unit rank at least $1$) you just want *some* nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in $\mathcal O_K$ such that the natural reduction map $\mathcal O_K^\times \to (\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p)^\times$ is surjective, but you don't care which prime ideal it is?